# In Javascript using try / catch, besides the error message how can I catch function name and all arguments names/values passed?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to create a **generic** debugging routine using try / catch, within the catch segment I'd like a piece of code which will log the function name and all params passed (name => value).

Is this possible?

```
try{
    // code
} catch(e) {
    var function_name = ''; // how can I get this?
    var function_params = ''; // how can I get this?
    var errorText = 'UNEXPECTED ERROR: \n\n Error Details: '+e.toString();
    errorText = errorText+' Called:'+function_name+'('+function_params+')';
}
```

Comment: Is `function_name` supposed to be the name of the function that contains the `try`/`catch` block, or the name of the function within which the exception was raised, or . . . ?

Comment: `window.onerror` Will fire for **most** errors that can occur, but not all.

Comment: can we get more context on this?  Is your try..catch supposed to be inside a function that wraps the other function, or inside the function that's throwing the error?

Comment: See here: http://jsfiddle.net/jJptv/ Also note that the global `event` object will be an `errorEvent` object.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome and Firefox you can use `e.stack` but no such luck in Internet Explorer.

The `stack` property is an array that you can loop over. It might differ a bit from browser to browser but it shouldn't be too hard to make a readable stacktrace.

You currently can't catch the arguments in all browsers.

In Chrome you might need to use:

```
Error.prepareStackTrace = function (error, stack) {
    return stack;
};  // augments Chrome's Error.stack property with context data
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `arguments.callee` for the function name

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee

Comment: _Warning: The 5th edition of ECMAScript forbids use of arguments.callee() in strict mode._

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an exact answer because I don't give the function Name but this returns the entire function body...

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/sS6sY/

```
Object.prototype.getArgs = function(){
//returns the arguments passed to a function.        
var els = [];
        for(i=0; i< this.arguments.length; i++){
            els.push(this.arguments[i]);
        }

        return els.join(',')
}

Object.prototype.getMethod = function(){
    //returns the function as a string.
    return this.constructor;

}

var Foo = function(){
   this.arguments = arguments;
   try{
        throw {
            name: 'Oops',
            message: 'Didn\'t mean to make a Foo!'
        }
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log(this.getArgs());
        console.log(this.getMethod());
    }
   }
```